# How do I anchor elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, anchor

I am use to working with windows forms, but recently I had started to work on WPF.
But I got into trouble when trying to anchor elements, the only solution I found online was to             use the Dock element.
(It hadn't worked) On top of that I want some of my elements to behave like the       anchor=right,left, button.
How can I do so?(for a tab control).

Comment: Have you tried HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" for your "right+left"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "anchoring" in WPF like there was in WinForms.  WPF has many options to control your layout and uses a combination of layout containers: `DockPanel`, `Grid`, `StackPanel`, etc.  And layout attributes like `HorizontalAlignment`, `VerticalAlignment`, etc.

I would suggest that you read up on things on the layout containers, `DockPanel`, `Grid`, and `StackPanel` being the most popular (at least in my experience).

On the upside, I've personally found the layout system in WPF to **much better** and powerful than WinForms, once you get the hang of it.

Comment: +1 Also, I love the following site for a quick visual look at WPF's layouts: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFLayoutQS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use `Margin` (not really needed), `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

**EDIT**

You drag/drop a control and then right-click the control. Select Reset Layout -> All. Then set or drag the margins. Note that this behavior might be different depending on the container control.

You can click the arrows between the control and its container to toggle between fixed size and margins (docking)

Comment: This works, But it stretches to all the screen, what if I want it only in some areas, and not specifically the borders?

Comment: @agam360 - use margins. What do you mean with 'some areas'?

Comment: When I placed(dragged and dropped) my element on a winForm app, and added an anchor to it, it staid anchored to that position. How can I get the same effect in WPF?

Comment: @agam360 - I added to my answer.